# Is it possible to format Angular server-side based on user data?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

In Angular 9 is there a way to build my Angular app and then whenever the client requests the page modify it based on data sent in that request?

For example run it through an Express templating engine such as EJS or PUG (aka Jade)?

The purpose behind this is that I need to ensure that certain parts of my application are never sent to the client unless they have a specific authentication token.

Here's an example of what I want (and works) in EJS:

```html
<div>Hello!</div>

<% if (username === "Tester") { %>
    <div>This contains sensitive admin forms!</div>
    <div>People shouldn't know that these exist!</div>
<% } %>
```

This is possible in Angular from what I understand, however either user information isn't available as it's not compiling at runtime, or it has to be processed by the client - which is a major security issue.

Is there any way to get this, or something similar to work in Angular?

Comment: Just don't put your sensitive data in your angular templates. Make a request to your server and look for your specific authentication token. If it's not there, just don't send your sensitive data to the client.

Comment: The sensitive data consists of elements such as buttons and inputs to an admin panel.

I can't just make a separate file per permission level and send them based off of that? Surely separating single elements into different files wouldn't be an ideal solution?

Comment: It's unclear what *"major security issue"* you perceive here. It seems unlikely the existence of buttons would need concealment, and your API endpoints should also require authentication. If you want to prevent access to certain routes based on the user, see e.g. https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards.

Comment: The panel will be shown to everyone, but will show more or less based off of your permission level, they're all in one route, and in EJS this is simple.

The security concern comes from lower level members having knowledge of tools that that shouldn't.

I was hoping to find a similar function within Angular.

Comment: You can certainly conditionally render parts of the template based on user data, *on the client side*. It's still not clear what you're trying to secure.

Comment: Isn't a simple `*ngIf` enough (something like `<div *ngIf="username=='Tester'">...</div>`)? Are you worried that someone will dig through your minified JS to see some buttons and input boxes?

Comment: These input boxes would confirm questions that the staff team are not allowed to answer, so it is a major security concern for them to be sent to the client.

Comment: Having input boxes hidden in your compiled JS as part of a template that is not displayed client side is not your problem, your problem is not checking permissions server side. So just hide the buttons and input boxes in your angular template and check permissions to modify data server side (which you also have to do when you use server side rendering, btw).

Comment: I know that the buttons wouldn't be able to do anything, but as I just stated - the very existence of these buttons would confirm any questions our userbase would have about how much power our staff team has - which is not information we provide.

My issue is not the permission checks when they click the button, its creating a permission check to never even send the button.

Comment: if you are really worried that somebody would dig through your compiled JS to find those buttons/input fields etc. you could put them into a lazy-loaded module and protect it with a guard at the client side and also prevent loading the module (it's just a JS file) from the server with whatever technology you use in your backend.

Comment: @sloth But wouldn't it be a hacky solution to split a single form into at least 6 different modules? More as the permission levels continue to get more complex.

Comment: True, but the point of client side rendering is that all the stuff is already at the client. Maybe you want to use server side rendering instead and let angular create static pages on your server instead. If that's an option for you then you don't have to resort to such hacky solutions. You can find an introduction [here](https://angular.io/guide/universal)